# Solr 4.x and SolrCloud

Tags: solr, solrcloud

It is not very clear to me whether SolrCloud is a separate package or a part of Solr package (in 4.x)? I was reading http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud. Initially I thought SolrCloud is a separate package but as I read thru the wiki page, I got an impression that SolrCloud is a part of the Solr package?

If someone could clarify, that will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud features are a part of Solr.

For production you would need to have ZooKeeper as separate application (it's can be run as part of Solr too, but it's not advised to do that in production)

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/SolrCloud